# tableview persisting cell image after reloading

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview with cells that when selected displays an image within the selected cell, this image then disappears when the cell is selected again, and so on. When i press a submit button the selected cells are remembered and the tableview reloads with new data. But when doing this all the new data loads but the selected cell image persists. I have tried calling tableView.reloadData() on the main queue but it still persists. The image also persists when i press the submit button several times.

Heres my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return currentQuestion.answers.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return tableView.frame.height/CGFloat(currentQuestion.answers.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    setSelectedArray()
    let cell: AnswersTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "answersTableViewCell") as! AnswersTableViewCell

    let text = currentQuestion.answers[indexPath.row]
    let isAnAnswer = currentQuestion.answerKeys[indexPath.row]

    cell.answerTextLabel.text = text
    cell.answerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
    cell.contentView.sendSubview(toBack: cell.answerView)

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell: AnswersTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AnswersTableViewCell {

        if cell.answerImageView.image == nil {

            cell.answerImageView.image = UIImage(named: "paw.png")
            selected[indexPath.row] = true

        } else {

            cell.answerImageView.image = nil
            selected[indexPath.row] = false

        }
    }
}

@IBAction func submitButtonWasPressed() {

    if questionNumber < questions.count - 1 {

        questionNumber += 1
        setCurrentQuestion()
        self.answersTableView.reloadData()
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the image back to its correct value in `cellForRow`. Cells in your table are reused between calls to `reloadData`, and since you're not touching the imageView, it's keeping its previous value. Looks to me like you want:

```
cell.answerImageView.image = selected[indexPath.row] ? UIImage(named: "paw.png") : nil
```

inside of `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`.

Comment: amazing, i tried something so similar but failed. Thanks!